# Scala Json Array to List of Objects in PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework

I tried to convert Json Array to List of Object in Play Framework using Scala. It only compiles if I put the code in Controller.
If I put the same code in a separate class, it does not compile and throw ***diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[T]]***

I have MyModule.scala file

```
case class ProductDetails(
                           id: String,
                           name: String
                           
                         )

object ProductDetails {
  implicit val ProductDetailsFormat= Json.format[ProductDetails]
}
```

It failed to compile if I put this code in a ServiceUtil.scala and invoke the method from Controller. It throws ***diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[List[T]]***

```
//Does not compile
class ServiceUtil(name: String){
   def getProductDetails(body:Array[Byte]) = {
      (Json.parse(body) \ "data" ).asOpt[List[ProductDetails]]
   }
}
```

Interestingly, the same code will compile with no problem if I put the code directly in controller

```
(Json.parse(body) \ "data" ).asOpt[List[ProductDetails]]
```

How can I resolve this? If I want to keep this code in ServiceUtil.scala

Thank you

Comment: Luke, use "-Xshow-implicits" compiler option (it might be "-Xshow-implicit" or  "-Xlog-implicits" or "-Vimplicits") or idea implicit hints. In any way this depends on imports of implicit instances in your classes. Add this info

Comment: Try also add type to your implicit, like implicit val ProductDetailsFormat: Format[ProductDetails]= Json.format[ProductDetails]. And be sure to have the right import

Comment: What version of Play are you using?

Comment: @mfirry
I use version 2.3.10

Comment: @user2963757
Added as suggested, still see the same error

Comment: Never had this problem before. Have you also tried to add a case class for your list of products, with an implicit format as well? And then do a Json.toJson[List[ProductDetails]] and the other way around, a Json.parse(yourdata). And add a test class for this as well. Should do the trick.

Comment: 2.3.10 is a very old version. Could you try and upgrade to a later release of Play?